# Damaged WAL exception in Hbase

Tags: hbase, wal

Why do we get damaged WAL exceptions in hbase. Not able to find anything definitive to look for

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HojwT.png)

Comment: any error log in hbase server?

Comment: All nodes are healthy. This only occurs when i bulk load in large volumes. Have not noticed this when running test cases of low data volume.